# VS2022 Android Device Manager and SDK Manager failing to download - cannot establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: android, xamarin, adb, visual-studio-2022

When using VS2022, I cannot update, create, or download any Android devices or SDK packages.

When I try to create devices in Android Device Manager and downloading/updating Android SDK stuff in Android SDK Manager it keeps failing with the following error each time:

> [23-11-22 11:26:46.25] System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error
> occurred while sending the request. —> System.Net.WebException: The
> underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust
> relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel. —>
> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote
> certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

[image: Android Device Manager Error]
[image: SDK Manager Error]

Steps I’ve tried from searching online:

- Disabled TLS 1.3 in registry
- Reinstalled Visual Studio
- Updated Visual Studio to latest version
- Added Device Manager, SDK Manager, and adb.exe to “Allowed Apps” in
  windows Firewall

Software versions:

- Visual Studio Professional 2022 V17.8.0.23
- Android Device Manager v17.8.0.23
- Android SDK Manager v17.8.0.31

Strangely, it works when I use Visual Studio Professional 2019 (v16.11.29), and the Device Manager (v16.11.09) and SDK Manager (v16.11.0.17) included with that. But I need the latest SDK versions which are only support in VS2022 afaik.

I've reported this issue to Microsoft, but they closed it as a duplicate and linked another issue without a solution.

Anyone any ideas on how to fix this?